# R - Plot lat/lon values with border of germany

Tags: r, plot, geolocation

i'am searching for an easy method to plot latitude/longitude values in R with a border line from germany.
e.g.

```
lat;lon
51;12
52;13
```

What can i do?

Comment: Look into the [Spatial Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html).

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty:

```
library(mapdata)
pts <- data.frame(lon = c(12,13), lat = c(51,52))    
map('worldHires','Germany')
points(pts)
```

[image]